# SQL perplexing join method

Tags: sql, relational-database, azure-sql-database, relational-algebra

I've been struggling with a certain section of a greater query I'm constructing. It basically attempts to place bank details of employees across a maximum of three columns based on whether they have one, two or three bank accounts in use.

[image: My Quandry]

I'm using an Azure SQL server through VisualStudio.

The context of the database is a set of employment parameters, banking, tax info that all needs to be joined up and exported out to then be pushed to an API. I've constructed the tables from old .csv's from janky old interbase servers so there's sometimes a bit of fuzziness surrounding the primary keys but each row is unique so selection can be worked around.

I can't find anything at all over the past few days on the net and was hoping somebody could even just point me in the right direction. I'm not begging for code here.

Any suggestions? Cheers!

Comment: Hi Brendan, the best way to get a good result on stackoverflow is to try and isolate the one thing you can't figure out and create a query that represents the problem. Also your link doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Derek, pardon this rookie. If looks as if sticky bit has fixed up the image as It's  loading on this page now. I had thought that I had isolated my problem but perhaps I have not phrased it properly. I've all the information I need for constructing the third table via a query but have no idea how to translate multiple columns across multiple rows based on the key EmpId.

Comment: downvoted? seriously? why?

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what can't be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Also see [mcve]. @stickybit Please don't inline inappropriate links--here, tell the poster to cut & paste the table as sql code and/or ascii art.

Comment: This is a faq, which you would find if you googled many clear concise statements of your question/problem goal. Read about database/sql pivoting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL (azure compatible) get values from one column as a row of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715643/t-sql-azure-compatible-get-values-from-one-column-as-a-row-of-data)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which database, so I'll try a "mostly" generic solution. You'll need to tweak this SQL according to the specific syntax of your database. Here's a shot:

```
select
    e.empid, e.name,
    a1.accountno as Account1, a1.bsb as BSB1,
    a2.accountno as Account2, a2.bsb as BSB2,
    a3.accountno as Account3, a3.bsb as BSB3
  from employee e
  left join (
    select accountno, bsb from account x1 where x1.empid = e.empid 
      limit 1
    ) a1
  left join (
    select accountno, bsb from account x2 where x2.empid = e.empid
      and x2.accountno not in (x1.accountno) 
      limit 1
    ) a2
  left join (
    select accountno, bsb from account x3 where x3.empid = e.empid 
      and x3.accountno not in (x1.accountno, x2.accountno) 
      limit 1
    ) a3
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is the pivoting, so I'll show how to do that -- here with conditional aggregation:

```
select t2.empid,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then accountno end) as accountno_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then bsb end) as bsb_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then accountno end) as accountno_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then bsb end) as bsb_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then accountno end) as accountno_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then bsb end) as bsb_3
from (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by empid order by accountno) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
group by empid;
```

I will let you figure out how to join in the rest of the information.  It really isn't that hard.

Also, note that the original ordering of the account is not preserved.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You have not shown any columns that capture the original ordering, so this orders by the account number.  If you do have an ordering column, then use it in the `order by`.